# disposing StreamController when polymer element is destroyed

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm creating a custom polymer element in dart that includes a StreamController. I've read that it's important to close your Stream controllers when they're done, so I'd like to know how I can do that within a polymer element. I've googled around on this, and I haven't been able to find a document explaining the life cycle of a polymer element in regards to when it is being disposed of (if it does at all). Am I missing something, does anyone know anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `attached`/`detached` callbacks.

See also https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods

Comment: But detached only fires when the element is removed from its parent. If it is then re-attached, I would need to re-create the StreamController. I'm looking for more of a dispose or destroy callback. Your suggestion may well be the only option, but I want to find out for sure.